# Compilation Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'ComboBox.ObjectCollection' to 'CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, compilation

I have this error in my code at this row

```
ObjectCollection items = comboBox1.Items;
```

the error is:

```
"Error CS0029   Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection' to
'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection'"
```

I need help to solve it please any one can help me? What should I do here?

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    ObjectCollection items = comboBox1.Items;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        MyClass myClass = (MyClass)item;
        string constr = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =" 
                        + myClass.Path + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes;\"; ");
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            comm.CommandText = "Select * From[" + myClass.TableName + "]";
            comm.Connection = con;
            using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
            {
                da.SelectCommand = comm;
                da.Fill(dt);
               dataTable.Merge(dt);
            }
        }
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
}
```

Comment: So, it's a compiler error, not an exception, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You problably are `using` another namespace which also defines this type. Declare the type explicetly:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection items = comboBox1.Items;
```

or use var:

```
var items = comboBox1.Items;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) three classes called `ObjectCollection`:

- [`ListBox.ObjectCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection?view=netframework-4.8)
- [`ComboBox.ObjectCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection?view=netframework-4.8)
- [`CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.objectcollection?view=netframework-4.8)

What the compiler is telling you, that `items` refers to `CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection` while `combobox1.Items` is a `ComboBox.ObjectCollection`.

So if you change your line to

```
ComboBox.ObjectCollection items = comboBox1.Items;
```

you get the correct variable type. Or you can just use `var` and let the compiler figure it out: `var items = comboBox1.Items;`.